# create a new environment by modifiying figure environment so that title will have the name Plate instead of Figure

Tags: graphics, floats, environments, thesis, renewcommand

I am currently working on my Ph.D. thesis and require assistance in creating an environment where I can insert a figure. However, I need the title of the figure to be named "Plate" instead. I have attempted to use a certain code, but I have encountered an issue where the Figure numbering does not start from 1. Instead, it continues from the numbering in the Plate environment that I created. Therefore, I need both the Plate and Figure environments to function simultaneously but with individual numbering. It is crucial that this works in "overleaf". Could you please help me with this?

```
    \documentclass{article}

     \usepackage{graphicx}

       \newenvironment{plate}[1][]{
        \renewcommand{\figurename}{Plate}
      \begin{figure}[#1]
}{
  \end{figure}
}
\newenvironment{topcaption}{
  \captionsetup{position=top}
}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{plate}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{LOAMR1B.png}
  \caption{This is a plate}
  \label{plate:example}
\end{plate}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{LOAMR1B.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps `\usepackage{float}` then `\newfloat{plate}{tbp}{plt}{}` where I used `tbp` as default placement as it is the case with figure in standard classes.  Then you can issue `\listof{plate}{List of Plates}` (pardon the probably senseless "Plates") as you would use `\listoffigures`.  Ah I forgot `\floatname{plate}{Plate}` for the captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new counters for plate and figure and then set the figure counter to the counter each time:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{platecnt}
\newcounter{figcnt}

\newcommand{\setfigurenumber}[1]
{
    \refstepcounter{#1}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{#1}}
}

\newenvironment{plate}[1][]{
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Plate}
    \begin{figure}[#1]
    }{
    \end{figure}
}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{plate}[h]
        \centering
        \setfigurenumber{platecnt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{LOAMR1B.png}
        \caption{This is a plate}
        \label{plate:example}
    \end{plate}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \setfigurenumber{figcnt}
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{LOAMR1B.png}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works perfectly. But when I use '''\listoffigures''',    it gives a list of all figures and plates.  When trying to use " \listofplates", it is not working (it gives an error). I need "\listofplates," so I need a list of plates on a new page. Please help me

Comment: Happy it helps. listofplates that is a different topic. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @vinothkumar see the comment below your question. That gives you the answer to both issues.